# Hidden x axis in R data set sunspots. Where?

Tags: r

When you fire up R and run

```
data('sunspots')
plot(sunspots)
```

It gives you a plot from 1750 to about 2000, and labels the x axis time.
How does it know it's time and where is it getting the dates from? `typeof(sunspots)` says `double`, and I don't see other dimensions.

Where does `plot()` get the time data from? It also does a line graph, not a dot plot with circles like it usually does by default. What is this voodoo?

Comment: Why not evaluate `str(sunspots)` and see what you have? The "voodoo" you refer to is R's S3 object system.

Comment: @John Coleman Thank you, it says "Time-Series [1:2820] from 1749 to 1984: 58 62.6 70 55.7 85 83.5 94.8 66.3 75.9 75.5" I was actually trying to remember what that function was. I couldn't remember it. So I guess "plot()" handles the Time Series class in a special way. Awesome, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I've never delved into the object oriented aspect of R. This gives me some reading to do.

Comment: The book "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham is probably the best place to learn about such details. The physical book is nice, but the material is also available online. For example [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) is its discussion of the S3 object system. It discusses the dispatch system. In the case of the `sunspots` data, what is happening is that `plot` sees that `sunspots` is a `ts` object and hence dispatches to `plot.ts` If you are coming from a Python background, you can think of an S3 class as a class where all methods are magic (hence your use of "voodoo" seems apt).

Comment: Adding to @JohnColeman 's comment, also consider John Chambers' book [Software for Data Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Software-Data-Analysis-Programming-Statistics/dp/0387759352).

Comment: Great suggestions, thank you both.